# implementing a JQuery function to trigger an event every time a DropDownList is selected

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i am new to the concept of MVC and JQuery i am stuck here please help

i am trying to Implement cascading DropDownList for my Project and I have achieved Implementing  cascading DropDownList using a Jquery function

my problem is that for my project i need  to increase the number of DropDownList  for that i have created a button that increases the rows of DropDownList , but the cascading DropDownList works only for the first row and not other for any other rows of DropDownList .

first row makes the call to the JQuery function implements cascading function, but from 2nd row there is call make to JQuery fuction

so i need help to call Jquery function every time a value from DropDownList is selected

my code is as follows

PartialView Code

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", options))
{
<div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading"> </div>
    <div class="panel-body">

        <div class="form-group col-md-offset-4 ">

            @Html.Label("Enter TimeSheet Date:")

            @Html.Editor("Date", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker" } })
        </div>

       <table class="table">              
           <tr>
               <th> </th>
               <th> Project </th>
               <th> Modules </th>
               <th> Task </th>
               <th> No of Hours</th>
               <th> Note </th>
           </tr>
          @for(int i=0;i< Model.CountForTimesheetForm; i++)
          {
           <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownList("ProjectName", new SelectList(Model.projectList, "Value", "Text")
               , "Please Select a Project", new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
                        <td>

               <select id="module" name="module" style="width:200px"></select></td>
               <td>@Html.Editor("TaskName", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>
               <td>@Html.Editor("NoOfHour", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>
               <td>@Html.Editor("Note", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>

           </tr>
          }

           <tr>
             <td>  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add Row</button></td>
           </tr>
       </table>



        </div>
    </div>
  }
```

Jquery Code for cascading

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#ProjectName').change(function () {
            $.getJSON('/TimeTracker/GetModules/' + $('#ProjectName').val(), function (data) {
                var items = '<option>Select a Modules</option>';
                $.each(data, function (i, module) {
                    items += "<option value='" + module.Value + "'>" + module.Text + "</option>";
                });
                $('#module').html(items);
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: You have multiple problems with this code. Your generating duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html and `$('#ProjectName')` will only ever get the first element with `id="ProjectName"` You also generating duplicate `name` attributes so you cannot bind to your model when you post back. You need to generate your controls in the `for` loop using `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m[i].ProjectName, new SelectList(...` and give your dropdownlist class names for that can be used for jQuery selectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are repeating the id attributes that should not be repeated on the labels of the page.

[HTML 5 specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute) says the same thing but in other words. It says that ID must be unique in its *home subtree*, which is basically the document if we [read the definition of it](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#home-subtree).

I hope it helps you.